# Printing # of button clicks at termination of program

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener, instance-variables

I have three JButtons labelled A, B, and C. After 10 seconds the program exits, and the total number of clicks is printed to console. I'm a complete newbie, and am having trouble getting the clicks to print. It always comes out with 0. I need the clicks from each button to count towards the total. I haven't fully grasped the nature of variables, it seems, so I'd like someone to shove it in my face so I can learn it, please.

```
a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     int _clicks;
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eco){
         _clicks++;
     }
 });
b.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     int _clicks;
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eco){
         _clicks++;
     }
 });
c.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
     int _clicks;
     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eco){
         _clicks++;
     }
 });

int delay = 10000;
 ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
     int _clicks;

     public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
         System.out.println("You clicked "+_clicks+" times! Woop");
         System.exit(0);    
    }
   };
   new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a instance field of `click` in your outter class, all your `_clicks` variables only have context within the `ActionListener`s within which they are created, meaning that their values are not shared out side of the instance of `ActionListener` within which the are defined

Have a look at [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html) for some more details

```
public class MyAwesomeClass extends ... {
    private int clickCount;

    //...

    a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        //int _clicks;
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eco){
            clickCount++;
        }
    });

    //...

    int delay = 10000;
    ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
        //int _clicks;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
            System.out.println("You clicked "+clickCount+" times! Woop");
            // It might be nicer to close the active window
            System.exit(0);    
        }
    };
```

new Timer(delay, taskPerformer).start();

Comment: Thanks for the response. Though, I still get an error at the first line "private int clickCount". I get the error "illegal modifier for parameter clickCount; only final is permitted". Googling didn't really help much.

Comment: You seem to have made it a local variable rather then an instance field as suggested. Did you check the linked tutorial?